Need help fixing - unable to open Android test DPC
I have a work profile installed on my Android device and test DPC is the device admin and everything was working is expected for the last several months. In the last 2 days I have been unable to open test DPC successfully within my work profile. I am not sure how to fix this or find the root cause for this. I tried to uninstall the Test DPC, but obviously the uninstall would not succeed because the app itself is an admin. I have a hidden messaging app within my work profile and hence I am trying to not remove the entire work profile and recreate. If there is a way to fix this and use DPC again to unhide my app, that would be helpful.
Here is the video preview of what is happening - https://photos.app.goo.gl/Uu5M1Z1JTShWZCxc6
